# Ruby: trim or replace leading digits

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a string in the following form:

```
'123string89continues...'
```

What is the most elegant way to replace or trim the leading digits? Note, there can be more or less than 3 digits, but at least one will always be present.

```
'1string89continues...' # This can happen
'0123456789string89continues...' # This can happen

'string89continues...' # This cannot happen
```

Comment: I cant understand your concern please explain it more

Comment: If you want to update the string in place, you could: `string[/\d+/] = ''`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
'123string89continues...'[/\D.*/]
#⇒ "string89continues..."
```

Comment: Worth noting that `[]` notation is a shortcut for `String#slice`.

Comment: @sagarpandya82 [vice versa](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/0d036505997b489a7edfc07f99c0c95f9cb135ab/string.c#L10330), or, more precisely, they are [independent](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/0d036505997b489a7edfc07f99c0c95f9cb135ab/string.c#L10444) ruby calls to the same method  :)

Answer (score 3):

Try this one

```
"123asdads".sub(/A\d+/, "")
 => "asdads"
"1asdads".sub(/A\d+/, "")
 => "asdads"
"asdads".sub(/A\d+/, "")
 => "asdads"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`slice!`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/String.html#method-i-slice-21) to delete a specific portion from a string:

```
string = '123string89continues...'
string.slice!(/\A\d+/) #=> "123"
string                 #=> "string89continues..."
```

Comment: As the asker stated that the string always begins with a digit, the anchor `\A` is not strictly needed, but it does no harm and returns `nil` if the string does not begin with a digit, should a data check be desired. Contrast that with `str = "a2c"; str.slice!(/\d+/); str #=> "ac"`, which silently returns an incorrect result.

Comment: @CarySwoveland besides, the anchor also communicates the code's intent: remove one or more _leading_ digits.